# How to run a Play project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

hello I've been trying to find how to run a Java Play project in eclipse but I can't find an easy way. Here is what I've done

Create a project

```
play new testApp
```

Go to the folder

```
cd testApp
```

Eclipsify the project

```
play eclipsify
```

Open eclipse and import as an **existing project**, but then I don't know how to run the server from eclipse

NOTE: 
I know that I can run it in the console also. The problem is that I've added an Eclispe project to the buildpath using Eclipse so If I run it in the console I think it will not work, or am I wrong?

Comment: Run it from console: `cd /project/folder/of/testApp` > `play run` (in the same path where you invoked `play eclipsify`

Comment: I've edited the buildpath in Eclipse. If I run it from console it will not use the "Eclipse buildpath" or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know, I use IntelliJ and there's nothing bad with running from console.

Comment: Is it just me or is play one of the hardest frameworks in the universe to get up and running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play eclipsify creates a run configuration for you.

**Run --> Run Configurations  --> Java Applications --> testApp**

If you need to debug first run the application as indicated then

**Run --> Debug Configurations  --> Remote Java Applications --> Connect JPDA to testApp**

Comment: Thanks but I got this error when running it. `Usage: java javassist.tools.web.Webserver <port number>`

Comment: Try deleting your project from eclipse and rerun the command above.

Answer (score 16):

In newer versions of play, the command has changed to

```
play eclipse
```

Comment: This will never work out of the box, I have been trying for hours now ) :

Answer (score 7):

For Play 2.x.y, Activator is tool of choice

```
activator eclipse
```

or

```
./activator eclipse
```

to use project local activator copy (if exists)

Comment: This doesn't work in recent versions. `Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean)`. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/IDE seems to be the recent link and the config should go into `project/plugins.sbt`. After doing `activator eclipse`, only one project is found, but this seems a local issue here.

Answer (score 1):

The following procedure may be followed to compile and import sbt play project into eclipse IDE:

1. Go to your project folder and create text file `plugins.sbt` and add below code:

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.2")
   ```
2. To force compilation add below code to your project's `build.sbt` file:

   ```nonr
   EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile, compile in Test)
   ```
3. Ensure that Scala IDE is installed in eclipse (download from: [scala-ide.org](http://scala-ide.org/))
4. At command prompt type `sbt` to compile sbt play project.
5. After successful compilation, In sbt use command eclipse to create Eclipse project files > eclipse. Check for [info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
6. Go to eclipse IDE and use Import Wizard to import Existing Projects into Workspace

Answer (score 0):

I was trying "play eclipsify" but that wasn't working since it had changed to "play eclipse" and it works fine.