# How to run a Play 2.2.1 project from Scala IDE?

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, scala-ide, playframework-2.2

I have followed the [Play tutorial](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTodoList) to create a simple application, made sure it started using the "play" command and then running `play eclipse` I generated the eclipse project files. I finally imported the project into the latest version of Scala IDE bundle for OSX.

I would like to know if there is a way to run my application from within eclipse without having to use the shell to start play each time.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784090/how-to-run-a-play-project-in-eclipse), and the accepted answer says that a run configuration will be created in eclipse. In my case I can't see any, so that may have changed from version to version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no. You need to start the play server from command line if you want to load your application on a browser.

The long answer is that we (I'm a contributor to the Scala IDE project) are starting to work on [sbt integration](https://github.com/scala-ide/sbt-integration), which is the required building block for not having to run the play console on a terminal (because we can to do it for you in the background, once we have sbt support). My suggestion is to star the project I linked, and follow developments.